# Expandable ListView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I have a working expandablelistview code, which works fine as a standalone.
I have another working code for sliding tab views which I wrote separately.

Both these were written after going thru a number of blogs, android dev and stackoverflow questions.

When I try to combine and put the expandable listview in one of the fragments, I end up with an error, I am unable to resolve.

Here's the code from the Fragment piece:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
private static final String NAME = "NAME";
private static final String IS_EVEN = "IS_EVEN";

private ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Map<String, String> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        groupData.add(curGroupMap);
        curGroupMap.put(NAME, "Group " + i);
        curGroupMap.put(IS_EVEN, (i % 2 == 0) ? "This group is even" : "This group is odd");

        List<Map<String, String>> children = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            children.add(curChildMap);
            curChildMap.put(NAME, "Child " + j);
            curChildMap.put(IS_EVEN, (j % 2 == 0) ? "This child is even" : "This child is odd");
        }
        childData.add(children);
    }

    // Set up our adapter
    mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            groupData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
            childData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
            );
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}

}`
```

I keep getting error on the last line: **'The method setListAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter) is undefined for the type Fragment1'.**

The rest of the code shows no error.

Please help. How can I correct this problem.

Comment: may be help to u https://gist.github.com/mosabua/1316903

Comment: Thanks.. I tried this example but I am not getting any listview when I run this on AVD, it gives a blenk screen in the fragment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem myself.. For future reference, here's the code. Might be messy and needs cleanup, but it works for now!

```
  public class HotDeals extends Fragment {
private ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,                   Bundle              savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.saved_tabs, null);

return v;
}

private static final String NAME = "NAME";
private static final String IS_EVEN = "IS_EVEN";

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Map<String, String> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        groupData.add(curGroupMap);
        curGroupMap.put(NAME, "Group " + i);
        curGroupMap.put(IS_EVEN, (i % 2 == 0) ? "This group is even" : "This group is odd");

        List<Map<String, String>> children = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            children.add(curChildMap);
            curChildMap.put(NAME, "Child " + j);
            curChildMap.put(IS_EVEN, (j % 2 == 0) ? "This child is even" : "This          child     is odd");
        }
        childData.add(children);
    }
    ExpandableListView lv = (ExpandableListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
    // Set up our adapter
    mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            groupData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
            childData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
            );
    lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
}
```

@Divers & @Dixit - Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

[Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) do not contains method `setListAdapter`. [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) do. You have to extend your fragment from this class to solve this problem.

Comment: Tried ListFragment, the error I get is: 'The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) in the type ListFragment is not applicable for the arguments (ExpandableListAdapter)'.

Answer (score 0):

This post is almost 2 years old, but no answer in this page is a relevant one.

to answer PO question,

> > The method setListAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter) is undefined for the type Fragment1

It's because `setListAdapter` is a method of ListFragment or ListActivity which is waiting for a [`ListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) or its subclasses as argument. You get this error because you gave it a [`ExpandableListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) which does not implement the `ListAdapter` interface.

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer the question "How can I correct this problem?"