# expandablelistview.setAdapter(new SampleExpandableListAdapter(context, getActivity(), data));

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a problem with that whenever I use expandable listview in fragment the undoubtedly contain this error please check it.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.widget.ExpandableListView
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at com.made.in.india.ExpandableListView.Expandablelist.onCreateView(Expandablelist.java:23)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:850)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2191)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    ... 46 more
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/primary_text_dark.xml from drawable resource ID #0x1060001
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1993)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3337)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:436)
04-22 15:57:20.026: E/AndroidRuntime(18197):    at android.widget.Ada
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you check this sample code. It's also expandable list view not showing in fragment.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17646364/900338)

Answer (score 0):

I cant see your code but it looks like this is the line giving the error.

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/primary_text_dark.xml from drawable resource ID #0x1060001
```

Have you tried passing the context into the constructor and loading your resource from that?